# Encrypt big file with AES

Tags: java, memory, encryption, aes

I need to do some operations with a big file (>2GB).

I need to encrypt the file and I didn't want to store the >2GB file in memory and then encrypt it using the `Cipher` class. Is there any library to do this? Split the file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt any file without a buffer as large as the file. Just read it into a byte array of any size, call `Cipher.update()`, write the resulting byte array, repeat until end of stream, and finish by calling `Cipher.doFinal().` Or make your life easier and copy it using `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`. The buffer you use for these operations can be any size greater than zero, but I would suggest using at least 8192 bytes.

Comment: But I don't want to send anything, I just want to use Java to encrypt a file which is very large. If I do read the whole file into a byte array (so I can encrypt it using the `Cipher` class), the whole file would stay in memory. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: So what does RMI have to do with the question? Really you need to make yourself clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt *in place* by using random byte access. You'll find that the `ByteBuffer` class is used both for [random access to files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) as well as for `Cipher`.

For random access files it may be useful to use CTR mode encryption if you want to keep files at the same size or if you want to implement random access for them. Note that you *must* use a different IV for each file if you use CTR mode unless you don't re-use your keys (e.g. by basing an IV on the file path by using a hash, if that's unchanging). There are also other modes of encryption that are often used for disk and file encryption, it may be worthwhile to have a look.